# Text String to Date Conversion

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Cell: `Data!AA4`

Given: May 13 2011 12:00AM in text format.

Using:

```
=(DATE((MID(Data!$AA4,8,4)),VLOOKUP(MID(Data!$AA4,1,3),Sheet3!$A$1:$B$12,2,FALSE),MID(Data!$AA4,5,2)))
```

Returns: 13-May-11 in date format

Question: Is there a cleaner formula that can be used??

Comment: May is an unfortunate month to use as an example because the abbreviated month is the same as the whole month - how would `November 1st` be shown in your source data? Is it November 01, November 1, Nov 01 or Nov 1?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `=DATEVALUE(AA4)` ?

Maybe exclude the timepart by `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(AA4,LEN(AA4)-8))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in order for the text content of a cell is.

1. Extract  the year: `=MID(AA4;8;4)`
2. Extract the month (text in the cell): `=LEFT(AA4;3)`
3. Extract the day: `=MID(AA4;5;2)`
4. Doing and find the matching digits of months:

   ```
   =IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jan";1;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Feb";2;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Mar";3;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Apr";4;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="May";5;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jun";6;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jul";7;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Aug";8;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Sep";9;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Oct";10;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Nov";11;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Dec";12))))))))))))
   ```
5. Convert to Date:

   ```
   =DATE(MID(AA4;8;4);IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jan";1;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Feb";2;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Mar";3;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Apr";4;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="May";5;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jun";6;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jul";7;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Aug";8;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Sep";9;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Oct";10;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Nov";11;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Dec";12))))))))))));MID(AA4;5;2))
   ```
6. One formula and format date:

   ```
   =TEXT(DATE(MID(AA4;8;4);IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jan";1;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Feb";2;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Mar";3;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Apr";4;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="May";5;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jun";6;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Jul";7;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Aug";8;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Sep";9;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Oct";10;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Nov";11;IF(LEFT(AA4;3)="Dec";12))))))))))));MID(AA4;5;2));"dd-MMM-yyyy")
   ```

Cell format is not string. Format Date.

Answer (score 0):

@K_B is on the right track, but the problem is that your date is not in a format that Excel automatically recognizes as a date, so `DATEVALUE` will return `#VALUE!`.

This can be rectified by inserting a comma after the day in the original date text.

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(Data!AA4," ",", ",2),LEN(Data!AA4)-7))
```

This will return the serialized numerical date value Excel uses for date calculations. If the cell formatting is set to the desired format ("dd-mmm-yy"), this should give you what you want.

If you want to avoid using cell formats to display your data, you can wrap the whole thing in a `TEXT()` function and specify your format there. The output will still work for date calculations.

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ",2),LEN(A1)-7)),"dd-mmm-yy")
```